# Vuetify v-select wont re-route

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify's `<v-select></v-select>` and i'm trying to re-route the user to different paths, but i can't get it to work. Here's my code, can someone point out what i'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
<v-select
  :items="items"
  @:change="changePath"
  item-text="name"
  item-value="path"
  label="Select"
  solo
></v-select>

 export default {
    data: () => ({
      items: [
        {
          name: "machines",
          path: "/machines"
        },
        {
          name: "machines1",
          path: "/machines1"
        },
        {
          name: "machines2",
          path: "/machines2"
        },
        {
          name: "machines3",
          path: "/machines3"
        }
      ] 
   }),

  methods: {
    changePath(items) {
      this.$router.push({ path: this.items.path });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I noticed (which might be a typo), is the `@:change`. This should just be `@change`.

The second thing (which is probably the actual issue), is in the changePath method. 
You are assigning `this.items.path` to the path in the object but it should be the item passed to the method.

`this.$router.push({ path: items });`

//Edit: I created a small fiddle with a router-view as a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/eradima/ks0e3x82/)